# setting a multi-dimensional array value to a value of a different array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I am developing a program in which i need to set a multi-dimensional array value to the value of a location in a different array. I have an error that i can't seem to resolve i know its probably hiding in plain sight but i am relatively new to java so all help is appreciated.

P.S: the error message i receive is "cannot find symbol symbol:z0y0x0 location: class TheRangeOutpost ']' expected"

```
public class TheRangeOutpost {

    public int[][] z0y0x0 = new int[1][3];

    z0y0x0[0][0] = 0;



    public String[] views = {
    "you stand in a dark corner with a ruined mattress lay on the ground"
    };

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you are trying to run. I suspect that you are trying to access statically `z0y0x0` but you instantiated it non-statically.

Comment: im sorry but the entire project consists of about 13 files im not sure how i would go about sharing them with you

Comment: its not a runtime error either its netbeans giving me a red highlight

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
z0y0x0[0][0] = 0;
```

must be contained within a method/constructor/instance initializer.

A constructor example:

```
public TheRangeOutpost() {
  z0y0x0[0][0] = 0;
}
```

Comment: yes this worked thank you very much im very new to the concept of OOP (object oriented programming) this was a prefect fix

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the array in the constructor of the class.

```
public class TheRangeOutpost {

  public int[][] z0y0x0 = new int[1][3];


  public TheRangeOutpost() {
    z0y0x0[0][0] = 0;
  }

  public String[] views = {
    "you stand in a dark corner with a ruined mattress lay on the ground"
  };

}
```